# How To Select Vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

So I am a huge Blender newbie and had a very basic question. I'm importing models from a posing studio to edit in Blender, but when I switch to Edit mode and attempt to delete vertices I'm stuck on selecting bones instead of vertices, edges, and faces. I was able to successfully switch to editing vertices once, but I don't know how I did it. I'm wondering if there's a hotkey or easy way to switch to selecting and editing vertices rather than bones?

I included a picture of the bone select mode that I seem to be stuck in.

[image]

I apologize for the newbie question. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: you are in Edit mode but you have selected the armature, you need to switch back to Object mode, select the character object, and then Edit mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected the armature are already in edit mode for the armature hence you are only able to edit the armature and not the mesh.

1. Go back to object mode.
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to deselect everything.
3. Select the mesh only and not the armature. If you are having trouble selecting the object then go to the outliner and select the object by clicking on *Kanout.mesh*.
4. Now enter edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer :)